# Restricting the variables to take a fixed number of decimal places in Matlab

Tags: matlab, decimal, rounding, store, digits

I am coding an evolutionary optimization program in Matlab. I want all the variables to have limited number of decimal points. (The reason is to reduce the search space. For e.g., if 1 < x < 2 , I will have only 9 options for x if the number of decimals is fixed to one.) Using 'round' is okay, but computationally a bit expensive. I see that 'digits' fix, but in the memory it saves all the digits.

Any help is appreciated,
Many Thanks in advance,
Ahammed

Comment: I'm guessing that you're trying to do something like [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5514804)? `digits` is specific to variable precision symbolic math, which is slow, so it's probably not what you want. There's the [`Fixed-Point Designer`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/fixed-point-designer-for-matlab.html) toolbox, if you have it. Not sure about it's performance. You might also be able to use [integer datatypes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-summary.html#bqjg7rp) (e.g., something like `uint8(31415)` = `100*3.1415`).

Comment: From the above two replies, I decided to use integers ( if 1 < x < 2 and I want only one decimal, I will use 10 < x < 20 and x will be replaced by x/10) and to use `int8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way fixed-width optimisation is usually done is using large integers instead. 
For example, if you want to limit your computations to 6-digits precision, then you can just truncate all values multiplied by a million.

Arithmetic operations on integer types are fast and exact, compared with floating-point numeric formats. I'm not sure you would gain anything in terms of efficiency in Matlab though, given that numeric types usually default to `double` and that most functions require either `double` or `single` inputs.